# How to fix com.android.ddmlib.ShellCommandUnresponsiveException?

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]

Android Studio Gives this Error everytime

I have also attached the Screenshot for further reference.
How can I fix it ?

Comment: Before version 3.5.1 of Android Studio, when you click on the trash can icon to delete the Logcat, it will be deleted immediately. From 3.5.1 (3.5.2 inclusive), it takes too much time and sometimes the same error message appears. I dont know where to report that bug.

Comment: Need to kill adb every time after this.